# XML Schema Validation Error on xs:alternative (Eclipse)

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

Can you help me understand this error with a XML Schema document please? I'm trying to differentiate two types of the same element in this way (if the attribute "type" of the element "policy" is equal to "Reachability", the type of the element will be "Rpolicy", "Tpolicy" otherwise) :

```
<xsd:element name="policy" type="xsd:anyType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:alternative type="Rpolicy" test="@type = 'Reachability' "/>
        <xsd:alternative type="Tpolicy"/>
</xsd:element>
```

I'm using Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 and I get this error :

> s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'policy' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: alternative. def.xsd /RemoteSystemsTempFiles/xsd line 8  XML Schema Problem

Line 8 is

```
<xsd:alternative type="Rpolicy" test="@type = 'Reachability' "/>
```

Can you help me understanding the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Conditional Type Assignment](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)** and `xsd:alternative` require **XSD 1.1**.

The error message you're receiving indicates that your processor only understands **XSD 1.0**.

Comment: You're right. I tried with another processor and it works. I didn't know Eclipse doesn't understand XSD 1.1. Weird.